# How to avoid using cached page in certain cases when using Cache-Control headers inside getServerSideProps?

Tags: next.js

I'm working on a dashboard application below are the routes:

1. Client list - "/clients" - renders a list of clients - SSR
2. Add client - "/clients/new" - add new client entry - SSG

Things on mind:

The client list should have updated data and it should feel faster.
And I want to avoid the use of loader or skeleton UI (lower priority at the moment). I have tried SWR as well but I'm exploring all the other data fetching strategies to make it fast.

My concern is, that the applications work/feels really fast for the static pages but when I visit server render pages it takes time which is an obvious thing and I understood.

What I'm thinking is -- I will add the "Cache-Control" header to the server-rendered client list page because the clients are the same on each request unless I add a new client entry.

So my real Question is -- When I submit the "Add client" form when the cache is fresh and then route to the "Client list" page to see a new entry, is there any way I can tell NextJS, that I have added a client entry now, please don't use the cached client list. Such that NextJS will give me a fresh server-rendered client list page with updated data.

With this, the Client list page will feel faster because of the cached version, and on a new entry, it will show updated data.

Below is the code I'm using for the Client list page.

```js
export async function getServerSideProps({ req, res }) {
  res.setHeader(
    "Cache-Control",
    "public, s-maxage=10, stale-while-revalidate=59"
  );

  const clients = fetchClients();

  return {
    props: {
      clients,
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks but as this is a dashboard application, data will be dynamic and user-specific. And what I have understood is that we should use ISR when a page is common for multiple users. I'm just curious whether what I want to achieve (the description of the question) is the right thing? Else I will go with the SWR.

Comment: Premature optimization can derail any project and kill the timeline - I'd focus on building and not worry about saving the 500 or MS until later, or it becomes a problem.

Comment: To answer your questions. There is likely no benefit to using SSR if it's dynamic per user, behind a login screen, & your target users have good internet. I would do a static page & fetch the data client-side. Let your CDN/data/HTTP servers do the caching. This would be the skeleton approach, but it's faster for the user as the request only relies on the data & not the data and HTML. Check out optimistic updates - I use them via Apollo graphql caching, & it makes a great user experience and instant appearing UI. Data fetching libraries often have refetch callbacks that you can manually trigger

Comment: Hey @SeanW thanks for the advises. Sure thing, I am going with SWR and will do the optimistic updates.